# How to deal with this NSString correctly with cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsstring, cocos2d-iphone, nslog

I'm new with cocos2d so i've got a problem with my In-App Purchase Class Helper. I wrote game in Cocoa Touch and this class working perfectly, but i'm writing now the same game in Cocos2d and problem is with NSString.

Here are some snippets.

This method is called as first when i clicked some button. As you see `completeIdentifier` is simple string with `bundleIdentifier` and some string parameter. It's ok, in this place i can log this `completeIdentifier`.

```
- (void)prepareToPurchaseItemWithIdentifier:(NSString *)aIdentifier showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title description:(NSString *)description delegate:(id)aDelegate{

    self.delegate = aDelegate;

    identifier = aIdentifier;
    completeIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier], aIdentifier];

    askToPurchase = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:description delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Later", @"Yes", nil];
    askToPurchase.delegate = self;
    [askToPurchase show];
}
```

Next method is `UIAlertViewDelegate` method. Is called when i click `YES` on `alertView` from first method.

```
#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate Methods
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"%@", completeIdentifier);
    if (alertView == askToPurchase) {

        NSLog(@"[TSIAPHelper] Clicked YES. Prepare...");
        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {

            NSLog(@"[TSIAPHelper] Prepare to purchase [%@].",completeIdentifier);
            SKProductsRequest *request =[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                     [NSSet setWithObject:completeIdentifier]];
            request.delegate = self;
            [request start];

            pleaseWait = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please wait..." message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
            [activity startAnimating];
            [pleaseWait addSubview:activity];
            activity.frame = CGRectMake(125, 50, 36, 36);
            [pleaseWait show];
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"[TSIAPHelper] Purchase [FAILURE]. Prohibited by Parentar Control or something like that.");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Prohibited." message:@"Parental Control is enabled, cannot make a purchase. Turn off and try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: Whenever and anywhere i want to Log variable `completeIdentifier` i've got crash with selected line: `0x39e965d0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]` but i don't know what's that mean. And this line is selected:

```
NSLog(@"%@", completeIdentifier);
```

How can i fix it? In Cocoa Touch is working perfectly. When i use cocos2d isn't.

Comment: When i remove all `completeIdentifier` or other variable that store this: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier], aIdentifier]` and paste `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier], aIdentifier]` directly to NSLog or other place it's working correclty. It's very strange for me... Anyone knows where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you aren't using ARC. In this case completeIdentifier will be autoreleased.

Cocos2d clears the autoreleasepool every frame, whereas in Cocoa this is not strictly defined but may still crash. You can fix this by retaining or copying the string.

```
completeIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier], aIdentifier];
completeIdenfitier = [completeIdentifier retain];
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a problem.